# Impedance in AC circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Questions about impedance:

1. Is impedance only usable in AC circuits?

   For example, consider an RLC circuit but it is not AC.  Then I think that we can we calculate the current as $\varepsilon/Z$, where $Z$ is impedance.  But if that's incorrect, why can't we use impedance in this situation?
2. In RLC circuits with AC, if we calculate the amplitude of current with impedance, then the answer would be $\varepsilon_m/Z$.  But if we calculate the amplitude of current by deriving $Qe^{-\frac{Rt}{2l}} \cos\left(\omega t+\phi\right)$, then we will get a different answer.  What is the problem?

Comment: The impedance of capacitors is $Z_C=i/\omega C$, and the DC limit is $\omega\to 0$. If you're OK with putting in infinities in your calculations, and you can handle them correctly, then sure, it works - but you'll just get the same results as the naive DC analysis, in which capacitors are just open terminals and inductors are just wires.

Comment: As for your second question, you've almost certainly made an algebraic mistake or you are comparing results for two incompatible situations, but it is very hard to tell which without additional details on what you are doing and why you think those two results are different.

Answer (score 4):

For (linear) AC circuit analysis, it is assumed that

- The sources are sinusoidal and all have the same frequency $\omega_0$
- All transients have decayed (sinusoidal or AC steady state)

For this case, the voltage across and current through each circuit element is also sinusoidal with the same frequency $\omega_0$ and so, each has a [phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) representation.  The impedance of a circuit element is just the ratio of its voltage and current phasors.

The key point here is that *all* of the voltages and currents have the same sinusoidal form.

> For example, consider an RLC circuit but it is not AC. Then I think
>   that we can we calculate the current as ε/Z, where Z is impedance.

Stipulate that we have a series connected RLC circuit with a voltage source that is a step function $v_S(t) = V_S\,u(t)$.  If the voltage source were sinusoidal with frequency $\omega_0$, the impedance of the series RLC would be

$$Z_{RLC} =  R + j\left(\omega_0L - \frac{1}{\omega_0C}\right)$$

But, what is 'the impedance' of the series RLC for a step voltage across?  Does that even make sense to ask that?  Most importantly, note that the series current is *not* a step function.  That is, we can't find the series current by simply dividing the source voltage with a complex number $Z$ as you've suggested.

There is however, a frequency (or Laplace) domain approach that 'looks' like what you have in mind.  By transforming to the frequency domain, the series current is given by

$$I(\omega) = \frac{V_S(\omega)}{Z_{RLC}(\omega)}$$

$$Z_{RLC}(\omega) = R + j\left(\omega L - \frac{1}{\omega C}\right) $$

The time domain current can then be found by transforming $I(\omega)$ back to the time domain.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a series LCR circuit then you are trying to solve a differential equation of the form

$$L\frac{dI}{dt} +RI + \frac QC = V(t)$$

where $I$ is the current, $Q$ is the charge on the capacitor and $V(t)$ is the applied voltage.

The solutions of equations of this type can be thought of a being composed of two parts.

- A transient solution which dies away to zero with time.
- A steady state solution which is what happens after the transient solution has died away.

> we calculate the amplitude of current by differentiate $Qe^{-\frac{Rt}{2L}} \cos\left(\omega t+\phi\right)$

This has all the hallmarks of a transient solution because $I \rightarrow 0 $ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ with a frequency of $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{1}{LC}-\left ( \frac{R}{2L}\right)^2}$ which is the natural damped frequency of the circuit

This term would contribute to the current when the circuit was first switched on but would die away as time passed.

The current $\varepsilon_m/Z$ is added to the transient current but does not decay away and so it is the current after the transients have gone - it is the steady state solution and is the same frequency as the frequency of the voltage supply.

Here is my attempt to "illustrate" what happens graphically with the frequency of the transient being about ten times that of the steady state.
Note that after about $5$ units of time the transient has all but died away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answers about impedance:

1. "Is impedance only usable in AC circuits?"

   $\textbf{Yes.}$

   The way we define impedance requires the source of voltage to be sinusoidal  (or co-sinusoidal). And we define it this way because it is a convenient way to solve differential equations (a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, and the non-homogeneous term must be sinusoidal/co-sinusoidal).

   On [Wikipedia, we have this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#cite_note-6):
   "Impedance is defined as the frequency domain ratio of the voltage to the current."

   So you could say that we could have another kind of signals that are periodic but not necessarily $sin$ or $cos$ and still preserve the properties of impedance. However, the definitions we currently have for impedance, 
   $1/j\omega C$ (capacitor) and $j\omega L$ (inductor) 
   consider that our signal is a $sine$ or a $ cosine $ (the complex numbers come from [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)). I said twice that impedance was defined, I and hope you don't feel like it is a arbitrary decision to define it this way. Just to make it as clear as possible, it was defined this way because it is a convenient way to express AC circuits, so it makes sense that it is mathematically consistent with linear AC circuits (only) - please take a look at Alfred Centauri answer to see exactly what characterizes a linear AC circuit.
2. "In RLC circuits with AC, if we calculate the amplitude of current with impedance, then the answer would be $\varepsilon _{m}/Z$. But if we calculate the amplitude of current by deriving $Qe^{−Rt/2L}cos(\omega t+\phi)$, then we will get a different answer. What is the problem?"

   $\varepsilon _{m}/Z$ is the amplitude of the current of the sinusoidal part of the solution of the equation. $Qe^{−Rt/2L}cos(\omega t+\phi)$ is the transient part of the solution (Farcher answer is pretty elucidative about it) - remember that a linear AC circuit does not have a transient solution(we are assuming enough time has passed, so the exponential "dies").

   In fact, if we take a look at the language you used here
   " But if we calculate the amplitude of current by deriving $Qe^{−Rt/2L}cos(\omega t+\phi)$, then we will get a different answer"
   we can see a inconsistency: what is the amplitude of a function that is not even periodic?

$\textbf{However}$,

if, for example, we have the equation

$$  L\ddot{q} + R\dot{q} + q/C = E(t)  $$

and $E(t)$ is continuous, we can represent it by it's [Fourier Serie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) and apply the AC analysis on the first terms of the serie (by "the first" I mean "as many as you want"). Then put them together (superposition principle) to get an approximate solution - it is approximate but can be arbitrarily close to the exact solution, depends only of your computational will. 
It is not efficient, a numerical method for solving the equation would be way faster, but I think it is interesting.

While I was answering your question, I was wondering if we could make other definitions for impedance for source functions $E(t)$ that are note sinusoidal. Perhaps it is, but the impedance might get quite ugly.